# LUIS intent wrong prediction

Tags: android-intent, prediction, azure-language-understanding

I am developing sample test with luis, I have created sample intents in luis, it was working perfectly till yesterday, suddenly from today not predicting correctly, 
each time intent prediction is different, kindly advise

Answer (score 1):

@user2907940, without more information, we could only give broad assistance. When testing utterances, if the intent predicted is incorrect, have you made sure to reset it to the correct intent, and then in turn **Train** (top right) to save your changes?

Here are a few other resources as to how to improve the prediction accuracy:

- [Review endpoint utterances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/LUIS/luis-how-to-review-endoint-utt)
- [Add phrase list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/LUIS/luis-how-to-add-features)
- [Add patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/LUIS/luis-how-to-model-intent-pattern)

If you'd like further assistance, please provide the JSON of your language model.

Answer (score 1):

Are you testing through the API or within the LUIS testing panel? If you are testing through the API, make sure you have published your changes after training. You might have trained it correctly and made improvements, but unless you publish it, you won't see those changes reflected when you send API queries.